# Question about peverify errors

Tags: .net, peverify

When I run the peverify utility against my .NET exe, I get a few errors (classes, methods renamed):

```
[IL]: Error: [myapp.exe : namespace.class::method1][offset 0x00000027]
Instruction cannot be verified.

[IL]: Error: [myapp.exe : namespace.class::method2][offset 0x00000027]
Instruction cannot be verified.

[IL]: Error: [myapp.exe : namespace.class::method3][offset 0x00000313]
Instruction cannot be verified.
```

Is this something I should be concerned about? These methods all use the unsafe keyword, which I'm assuming is the cause for this error. But I can't find any documentation about this error online, so any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is not because you used the *unsafe* keyword.  It is because you wrote code that compiled because you used unsafe.  Yes, peverify will balk at such code.  it is the very nature of unsafe.  You can't have your cake and eat it too here.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that, but without any docs I just wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `stackalloc` in those methods? While I was playing around with this I discovered that if `stackalloc` is the first occurrence of unverifiable code then peverify spits out that error message and ignores the rest of the method. However, the opposite is not true. If `stackalloc` appears later in the method then the other errors will precede the error generated by the `stackalloc` statement. Maybe that is bug?

Consider the following example.

```
public static void Main()
{
  unsafe
  {
    int* a = stackalloc int[100];
    int* b = null;
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
[IL]: Error: [myassembly.exe : A.Program::Main][offset 0x00000007] Instruction cannot be verified. 
1 Error(s) Verifying myassembly.exe
```

However, if I comment out the `stackalloc` line then I get this result:

```
[IL]: Error: [myassembly.exe : A.Program::Main][offset0x00000004][found Native Int][expected unmanaged pointer] Unexpected type on the stack. 
1 Error(s) Verifying myassembly.exe
```

Comment: I am using stackalloc, and I think I can just safely ignore these errors.

Comment: @Jon: Yep, I thought you might be using `stackalloc`. You can definitely ignore the error if you are okay with running unverifiable code.